# Is there a quick way to determine if I already have a skin customization?

Tags: borderlands-2

As I am finding more skin customizations for my current character, alternate charters, and various vehicles, I'm finding it hard to keep track of what I already have and don't have.  If I've already got a skin, I'd rather sell or trade it - but I haven't found an easy way to tell if I already have it.  I realize I could go all the way to the nearest customization booth thing - but those are often not close.  Also, since I haven't tried it yet - will the game prevent me from wasting a skin customization I already have, if I try to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you view the item on the ground or in your inventory, under the name and type of customization, a red block of text says "Already Unlocked" if you have already unlocked it before.

You can sell it, or better yet, trade or give it to a co-op partner who doesn't have it yet.

[image: already unlocked customization]

Comment: +1 to both, but check for the excellent picture.  I guess I haven't gotten any dupes yet, despite my suspicion.  I wouldn't have missed the red text I don't think.

Comment: There are a lot of vehicle customizations, and many customizations for each class. And you can get and use (but not wear) customizations for other classes you are not currently playing.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the item, it says in red text under the name: "Customization Already Unlocked".